# @Transactional Spring Junit test not doing rollback

Tags: hibernate, spring, postgresql, junit, transactional

I try to set up a Junit test case for my dao layer.
However, I do *NOT* want the test data to be actually persisted to the DB.

So I thought I should do it transactionally and rollback after every test.
This leaves me with the following datasource setup:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClass="org.postgresql.Driver"
    p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:postgresql://***"
    p:user="***"
    p:password="***/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:packagesToScan="***"
      p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProps" />

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
```

The to-be-tested dao class is set up as follows:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class BallotBoxRepositoryHibernateImpl implements BallotBoxRepository {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
  public void saveVote(DaoObject v) {
    Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
    sess.beginTransaction();
    sess.save(v);
    sess.getTransaction().commit();
    sess.close();
  }
[...]
}
```

The actual persisting job *does* work nicely. However, the intended Rollback is never made:

```
INFO main transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener:292 - Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context [...]
```

The TransactionalTextExecutionListener is defined as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({WebTestExecutionerListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class DaoTest { ... }
```

I'm using an autowired member to access my dao methods:

```
@Autowired
private BallotBoxRepository repo;
```

***TL;DR***

JUnit test case is persisting test data even though it's stating that a rollback has been done.

Comment: 1. don't use manual transaction handling, use Spring 2. check the @Rollback annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case Spring-based transaction management doesn't work because you manage Hibernate transactions manually.

In order to use Spring-managed transactions you should do the following:

```
@Override   
public void saveVote(DaoObject v) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(v);
}
```

**See also:**

- [13.3 Hibernate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate)